# .NET Compare KnownColor to Color

Tags: .net, colors, compare

I would like to know how I can compare a "System.Drawing.KnownColor" with a "System.Drawing.Color".

Just testing with "IsNot" is not allowed. VB.NET tells me that these 2 objects are not comparable.

I see that KnowColor has the function "CompareTo" which does accept Color as an argument, but the return value is not a Boolean but an Integer. So I am not sure if that is really what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Color.FromKnownColor()` to get a corresponding `Color` instance at runtime, and then you will be able to compare them.